# Install grub on 2nd hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, grub

I have 2 HDs in my machine:

- Drive 1 with grub and my Windows XP OS
- Drive 2 with *only* Ubuntu 9.04

I would like to be able to boot directly from drive 2.  I am missing grub on drive 2... how do I add it?

EDIT: I ended up reinstalling the whole OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must use Live ubuntu and boot your system with it or boot your system with ubuntu on your first drive. then install your second grub:

```
$ sudo grub
```

This will return a location. If you have more than one, select the installation that you want to provide the grub files. Next, THIS IS IMPORTANT, whatever was returned for the find command use it in the next line (you are still at grub>. when you enter the next 3 commands)

```
grub> find /boot/grub/stage1
```

Again use the value from the find command i.e. if find returned (hd0,1) then you would enter root (hd0,1)

```
grub> root (hd?,?)

grub> setup (hd0)

grub> quit
```

Comment: I tried that already but the system still does not boot... maybe grub isn't the only thing missing...

Comment: You'll also need to configure your system BIOS to boot from the second drive.  Default is the first drive

Comment: @EmmEff: I also did that already but I still only get the blinking cursor at the top left-hand corner...